# Media query is not working for Retina

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm trying to develop a site to support Retina. I have two images: the regular size and 2x version. My code does not appear to work. I'm on Retina and everything still looks pixelated for me.

```
header {
background: url(../images/header.jpg) no-repeat;
float: left;
height: 301px;
width: 1000px;
} 
@media  only screen and (-moz-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
        only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3/2),
        only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
        only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) 
        {
            .header {
            background: url(../images/header_2x.jpg) no-repeat;
            }
            .logo {
            background: url(..images/logo_2x.png);
            }
        }
.logo {
    background: url(../images/logo.png) no-repeat;
    display: block;
    height: 38px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 63px;
    width: 194px;
}
```

I'm not quite sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You have the regular styles *after* the media queries, so they're overriding the media queries. Either reverse the order or increase the specificity of your @media rules. (It's all about the meaning of "cascading" in CSS. :-) )

Comment: ralph.m: For the .logo span, if I place it before the media query, it doesn't show up at all. It only displays if I put the .logo after the media queries, but even then it doesn't show crisp like it should; it's pixelated.

Comment: There's something else going on there then. But the last one in the CSS order will apply, so the media query must come first, or be more specific, to work.